# Deciding whether to train a saved model or start a new one in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, methodology

I'm using Keras for various machine learning projects and save my models after every training run. Let's say I want to do a training session for an algorithm - how do you decide whether to (1) load a saved algorithm and train it or (2) start training the algorithm from scratch? Some potential approaches I thought of:

1. Only load a saved model when the new, labeled, examples differ significantly from what the saved model was trained on
2. Always train a new model since data is data
3. Always train a saved model since even small sampling variations can have an effect on the algorithm
4. Always train a saved model as soon as the input & output shapes are determined; you should only be training a model from scratch once.